# Scala: How do I compose a list of operations into a free monad?

Tags: scala, free-monad

I have a free monad working that does what I want:

```
type FreeOperation[F] = Free[Operation, F]

sealed trait Operation[O]
case object IdentityOperation extends Operation[GraphTraversal[_, _]]
case class LabelOperation(label: String) extends Operation[GraphTraversal[_, Vertex]]
case class HasOperation(has: String, within: List[_]) extends Operation[GraphTraversal[_, Vertex]]
case class InOperation(in: String) extends Operation[GraphTraversal[_, Vertex]]
case class OutOperation(out: String) extends Operation[GraphTraversal[_, Vertex]]
case class InEdgeOperation(inEdge: String) extends Operation[GraphTraversal[_, Edge]]
case class OutEdgeOperation(outEdge: String) extends Operation[GraphTraversal[_, Edge]]
case class InVertexOperation(inVertex: String) extends Operation[GraphTraversal[_, Vertex]]
case class OutVertexOperation(outVertex: String) extends Operation[GraphTraversal[_, Vertex]]
case class AsOperation(as: String) extends Operation[GraphTraversal[_, _]]
case class SelectOperation(select: List[String]) extends Operation[GraphTraversal[_, _]]

object Operation {
  def identity: FreeOperation[GraphTraversal[_, _]] = Free.liftF(IdentityOperation)
  def label(v: String): FreeOperation[GraphTraversal[_, Vertex]] = Free.liftF(LabelOperation(v))
  def has(h: String, w: List[_]): FreeOperation[GraphTraversal[_, Vertex]] = Free.liftF(HasOperation(h, w))
  def in(i: String): FreeOperation[GraphTraversal[_, Vertex]] = Free.liftF(InOperation(i))
  def out(o: String): FreeOperation[GraphTraversal[_, Vertex]] = Free.liftF(OutOperation(o))
  def inEdge(ie: String): FreeOperation[GraphTraversal[_, Edge]] = Free.liftF(InEdgeOperation(ie))
  def outEdge(oe: String): FreeOperation[GraphTraversal[_, Edge]] = Free.liftF(OutEdgeOperation(oe))
  def inVertex(iv: String): FreeOperation[GraphTraversal[_, Vertex]] = Free.liftF(InVertexOperation(iv))
  def outVertex(ov: String): FreeOperation[GraphTraversal[_, Vertex]] = Free.liftF(OutVertexOperation(ov))
  def as(a: String): FreeOperation[GraphTraversal[_, _]] = Free.liftF(AsOperation(a))
  def select(s: List[String]): FreeOperation[GraphTraversal[_, _]] = Free.liftF(SelectOperation(s))
}

def operationInterpreter(traversal: GraphTraversal[_, _]): (Operation ~> Id) =
  new (Operation ~> Id) {
    def apply[A](input: Operation[A]): Id[A] =
      input match {
        case IdentityOperation => traversal.asInstanceOf[A]
        case LabelOperation(label) => traversal.hasLabel(label).asInstanceOf[A]
        case HasOperation(has, within) => traversal.has(has, P.within(within: _*)).asInstanceOf[A]
        case InOperation(in) => traversal.in(in).asInstanceOf[A]
        case OutOperation(out) => traversal.out(out).asInstanceOf[A]
        case InEdgeOperation(inEdge) => traversal.inE(inEdge).asInstanceOf[A]
        case OutEdgeOperation(outEdge) => traversal.outE(outEdge).asInstanceOf[A]
        case InVertexOperation(inVertex) => traversal.inV().asInstanceOf[A]
        case OutVertexOperation(outVertex) => traversal.outV().asInstanceOf[A]
        case AsOperation(as) => traversal.as(as).asInstanceOf[A]
        case SelectOperation(select) => {
          if (select.isEmpty) {
            traversal
          } else if (select.size == 1) {
            traversal.select[Any](select.head).asInstanceOf[A]
          } else {
            traversal.select[Any](select.head, select.tail.head, select.tail.tail: _*)
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

I can call it like so to create a program:

```
def selectQuery: Free[Operation, GraphTraversal[_, _]] =
  for {
    _ <- label("person")
    _ <- as("people")
    _ <- outEdge("created")
    _ <- has("weight", List(1.0))
    _ <- inVertex("software")
    _ <- as("software")
    x <- select(List("people", "software"))
  } yield x

val traversal = graph.traversal.V()
val result = selectQuery.foldMap(operationInterpreter(traversal))
```

Cool! But here is the problem:

I have a `List[Operation]` that I would like to translate into this monadic structure... how do I do that?

```
def composeQuery(query: List[Operation[_]]): FreeOperation[GraphTraversal[_, _]] = {
  query.foldLeft(???) (??????)
}
```

What is the right way to translate my `List` of `Operations` into the free monad that I can pass my interpreter?

Comment: Would you not map `Free.liftF` over the collection, to create a list of monads, and then use the monadic `sequence` function to sequentially compose the monads?

Comment: @jon-hanson This was failing for me, but I replaced it with `sequenceU` and it worked! Apparently there is some scala issue for this: https://github.com/milessabin/si2712fix-plugin

Comment: Yep, `sequenceU` is the Unapply variant of `sequence`, required to work around [SI-2712](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712) - more info [here](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Unapply.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map `Free.liftF` over the collection, to create a list of monads, and then use the monadic `sequence` function (actually `sequenceU` as you point out) to sequentially compose the monads.